# GASでのメール送信について: 1 日にサービス email を実行した回数が多すぎます

Tags: google-apps-script

Gsuiteに契約してから試用期間を終えて運用開始後に下記のエラーが来ました。

```
Summary of failures for Google Apps Script: XXXX

apps-scripts-notifications@google.com
2020/02/16 5:19 (1 日前)
To 自分

スクリプト XXXX を正常に完了できませんでした。失敗のまとめを下記に示します。このスクリプトのトリガーを設定したり、今後の失敗の通知の受信設定を変更したりするには、ここをクリックしてください。

概要:

エラー メッセージ   カウント
1 日にサービス email を実行した回数が多すぎます。（行 50、ファイル「コード」）   28

起動  関数  エラー メッセージ   トリガー    End
20/02/15 5:19   allplay 1 日にサービス email を実行した回数が多すぎます。（行 50、ファイル「コード」）   formSubmit  20/02/15 5:19
・
・
・
```

GASでは試用期間が終われば1500件まで送信できると思っていましたが違うのでしょうか。

お手数ですがどなたか分かりませんでしょうか。
サポートにチャットしたらコアサービスではないのでサポート外といわれました。

Comment: [ToやCc、Bccも含めて件数と見なされるようです。](https://attrise.blog/ceo/archives/12873) / 複数の宛先や繰り返しで実行しているようであれば、まずはエラーで示された通りに件数が妥当なものかを確認する必要があるかと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。色々調べたのですが、現在の最大送信可能数のコマンドで算出してみたところ最大100件の計算でした。その後いろいろなところで調べた結果、１回目の支払いまではプランは有料プランだが制限は無料プランという仕様のようでした。１回目の請求後にまたコマンドを走らせて確認してみます。